# What are Frameworks for emotions?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, emotion

I have been fascinated by Pultchicks wheel of emotion and how it puts emotions into polar opposites and gives ways to combine emotions to derive others or break down a particular emotion to its constituent parts.

I know its been quite a while since it was introduced.

As someone who only dabbles with psychology as an interest, I want to know:

- Is it considered an important framework in understanding emotion?
- Are there more accurate / recent / biological research based similar models?

References: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Plutchik
[image]

Comment: Related: [Standard Academic set of emotions, and cognitive functions](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/17265/7001), [What is the most comprehensive system of describing human emotions or states of mind?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/8510/7001), [Number of core feelings?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/24549/7001)